# Can I connect to my Raspberry Pi 3 with neither an internet connection nor Ethernet cable?

Tags: connection, ethernet-port

I am trying to learn how to connect to my Raspberry pi 3 to my laptop without internet or a router. I know some have suggested that I use an Ethernet cable, but my computer (Windows 10) does not have an Ethernet port. I do have a cable with a USB connection on one end and an Ethernet connection on the other. That or I have a USB/Ethernet adapter. I am a beginner, so any help will be welcomed and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The Pi is designed to be used with a router (networking will automatically configure). You can get limited connectivity with an Ethernet connection. If you don't have one, how you configure your laptop has nothing to do with the Pi. If your laptop has network connection you should be able to connect the Pi similarly.

Comment: Start here https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-samba-in-ubuntu-for-file-sharing/  I am implemeting similar task - using Eclipse files / workspace on Pi and running Elsipse on connecetd PC. Have only part of it done.

Comment: The question title doesn't really match the details: title says no Ethernet cable, but question then talks about using an USB Ethernet adapter, so a cable is required. So the title might be partially misleading?

Answer (score 1):

I directly connected my Raspberry Pi 3 to my MacBook (which has no Ethernet port) using a USB Ethernet adapter, plus a short ethernet cable and an ethernet crossover adapter.  I could then ssh directly from the Mac to raspberrypi.local .  No internet, router, or video monitor needed.

If you do this, make sure ahead of time to enabled ssh on your Raspberry Pi's SD card (boot/OS).

I then used the wired ethernet connection to configure my Raspberry Pi's WiFi adapter as an access point (with an IP address and DNS services), and could reconnected from my Mac to the Pi over WiFi (again, no router needed).

Yet another option is to get a USB debug/console cable such as: https://www.adafruit.com/product/954

Yet another option is to use a serial port interface board/hat on the Pi and a USB to serial adapter with your laptop.

Comment: The same setup allowed me to to directly connect an iPad or iPhone plus a Camera Connection kit (Lightning-to-USB adapter) to my Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Ethernet patch or straight through cable you can directly connect the Ethernet port of 2 computers together. This is different from the common Ethernet cable which crosses the 4 pairs of wires. This is termed a cross over cable and is used to connect computers to switches and routers.

Patch cables are also used with patch panels and connecting switches and routers together if they do not have a smart port.

Comment: OP says his laptop has no Ethernet port.

Comment: @McLead but he also says he has a "USB to Ethernet" adapter, that sounds to me a USB network card (it's not very clear what he has got, though).